# Generate URL when domains method is used

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Giving this route:

```
Route::domain('{shop_seo_code}.shops.domain.com')->group(function () {
    Route::any('/', [
        'as' => 'shops_view',
        'uses' => 'Shops@view'
    ]);
});
```

How can I generate the full URL using "route" function? as I also need, to somehow, provide "shop_seo_code".
Example: `route('shops_view', ['shop_seo_code' => 'shop1']);`

Thanks!

Comment: Laravel should be able to do this automatically for you. If this conflicts with main root website URL routes, then you could probably give a different route name to avoid conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data to your web.php file.

If `{shop_seo_code}` can be multiple values at once, you can define them in config or create a model that's bound to that variable.

Then you can simply call `route('shops_view', ['shop_seo_code' => 'something'])` in your view.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this one too but it seems I wasn't careful enough.